# How to sort tuples on linking begin and end value in a list [(a, b), (b, c),(c, d)]?

Tags: python

I need some help on a function I wrote:

Where the input is, (for example): `[(g,h),(a,b),(c,d),(h,i),(b,c)]`

where `a,b,c,d` and `g,h,i` are random numbers

and the output will be: `[(a,b),(b,c),(c,d)]` and `[(g,h),(h,i)]`

or: `[(a,b),(b,c),(c,d),(g,h),(h,i)]`

I'm at beginner level. So my code hereunder has still some other issues to be resolved (it's work in progress). But I think it shows the basic idea how I think this can be solved. There is surely a much more elegant (and shorter) solution?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code so far:

```
    def sort_tuples(random_tuple_list):
        RTL = random_tuple_list
        Startpoint = RTL.pop(0)
        def sort_rec(RTL, Startpoint):
            if len(RTL) == 0:
                 return []
            temp_list = [Startpoint]
            for idl, tup in enumerate(RTL):
            if tup[0] == Startpoint[1]:
                temp_list.append(tup)
                del RTL[idl]
                continue
            if tup[1] == Startpoint[0]:
                temp_list[0:0] = [tup]
                del RTL[idl]
                continue
            if tup[0] == temp_list[-1][1]:
                temp_list.append(tup)
                del RTL[idl]
                continue
            if tup[1] == temp_list[0][0]:
                temp_list[0:0] = [tup]
                del RTL[idl]
                continue
            if idl == (len(RTL)-1):
                subtemplist = sort_rec(RTL, RTL.pop(0))
                if subtemplist == None:
                    return temp_list

                if subtemplist[-1][1] == temp_list[0][0]:
                    temp_list[0:0] = subtemplist
                    return temp_list
                if subtemplist[0].coords[0] == temp_list[-1].coords[1]:
                    temp_list.extend(subtemplist)
                    return temp_list
                else:
                    return temp_list, subtemplist
        return sort_rec(LSL, Startpoint)
```

Comment: what if you have `(a, b), (b, c), (c, a)`?

Comment: I guess for (k1, k2) there's always: k1<k2. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the items into a dictionary with the first item as the key (since that’s the start of ech item). Then, as long as the dictionary is not empty, get the smallest key and start a new sequence with it, following the links as you find them in the dictionary. If you hit the end of a sequence, then start again by finding the next smallest key in the dictionary.

```
>>> d = [('g','h'),('a','b'),('c','d'),('h','i'),('b','c')]
>>> links = {x[0]: x for x in d}
>>> lst = []
>>> while len(links):
        start = min(links.keys()) # get the next start
        while start in links:
            link = links[start]
            del links[start]
            lst.append(link)
            start = link[1]

>>> lst
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('g', 'h'), ('h', 'i')]
```

Of course this solution support no circles, or constructs where multiple links exist to the same element (the input may have them, but they are silently ignored).

Comment: thanks! This solution worked perfectly for me, except for one thing: Instead of: min(links.keys()), I used max(links.keys())